# Display xtable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, xtable

I want to display a data table in shiny with rotated column headers.
I see the option in xtable package to do this using rotate.colheaders
I cannot get the table to display (without all the printed formats) in shiny, all I get is a text string displaying the latex generation (see below).
I suspect that this is a fairly elementary point as I know that I am missing something - I just don't know what!

See minimised example of server.r code and output below

server.r code:

```
output$mytable <- renderUI({
    tab <- matrix(rep(1,6),nrow=3)
    rownames(tab) <- c('col1','col2','col3')
    M <- print(xtable(tab, rotate.colnames=TRUE))
})
```

Output in shiny app:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-3 package % Wed Oct 22 13:31:00 2014 \begin{table}[ht] \centering \begin{tabular}{rrr} \hline & 1 & 2 \\ \hline col1 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ col2 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ col3 & 1.00 & 1.00 \\ \hline \end{tabular} \end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use renderTable in server.r and tableOutput in ui.r

In server.r:

```
output$mytable <- renderTable({
    tab <- matrix(rep(1,6),nrow=3)
    colnames(tab) <- c('col1','col2')
    tab
    })
```

In ui.r add:

```
tags$head( tags$style( HTML('#mytable table {border-collapse:collapse; } 
                             #mytable table th { transform: rotate(-45deg)}'))),
column(6,tableOutput("mytable"))
```

Comment: When implementing the code above I get the following error:                No applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Can you test again please - I made some quick changes

Comment: This appears to work well now. The only remaining issue is with the column header. Instead of a rotated header it is still a text string: \begin{sideways} col1 \end{sideways}

Comment: You are right - I checked myself in a test app I created. I expected it to work as other xtable settings (like include.rownames) work. You will have to add some css code into your ui.r to rotate the column headers. See my updated answer above.